# How to get values of array textboxes generated during from onload event

Tags: c#, arrays, winforms, textbox, onload-event

I am having trouble retrieving values of array textboxes generated from runtime in onload event. here is the code.

from form onload event:

```
private void frmMain_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{           
TextBox[] txtFldNames = new TextBox[15];
int x = 155, y = 65, w = 300, h = 20;

for (int i = 0; i < 15; i++)
{
    y = y + 30;
    txtFldNames[i] = new TextBox();
    txtFldNames[i].Location = new System.Drawing.Point(x, y);
    txtFldNames[i].Size = new System.Drawing.Size(w, h);
    this.Controls.Add(txtFldNames[i]);
    txtFldNames[i].ReadOnly = true;
    txtFldNames[i].BackColor = Color.White;
}
}
```

now how do I access the textbox values from a button?

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
     //what to do here?
}
```

I already tried this one below but it does not work. All I get are null values. So please kindly point me into the right direction

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    TextBox[] txtFldNames = new TextBox[15];

    for (int j = 0; j < 15; j++)
    {
        txtFldNames[j] = new TextBox();
        MessageBox.Show("" + txtFldNames[j].Text);
    }
}
```

here is the full code:

```
public partial class classMain : Form
{
    public frmMain()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void frmMain_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        TextBox[] txtFldNames = new TextBox[15];
        int x = 155, y = 65, w = 300, h = 20;

        for (int i = 0; i < 15; i++)
        {
            y = y + 30;
            txtFldNames[i] = new TextBox();
            txtFldNames[i].Location = new System.Drawing.Point(x, y);
            txtFldNames[i].Size = new System.Drawing.Size(w, h);
            this.Controls.Add(txtFldNames[i]);
            txtFldNames[i].ReadOnly = true;
            txtFldNames[i].BackColor = Color.White;
        }
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //what to do here?
    }
}
```

Comment: You need to show all the code from the onload event. Is `txtFldNames` in the onload event in a global or local scope? The code you tried is creating a new array of textboxes where you don't set the text, that's why it's null.

Comment: sorry my bad. the code has been edited containing the full onload event

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given the full code you can do something along this way:

```
public partial class classMain : Form
{
    // Move your list to a global scope in the classMain form.
    TextBox[] txtFldNames = new TextBox[15];

    public frmMain()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void frmMain_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        int x = 155, y = 65, w = 300, h = 20;

        for (int i = 0; i < 15; i++)
        {
            y = y + 30;
            txtFldNames[i] = new TextBox();
            txtFldNames[i].Location = new System.Drawing.Point(x, y);
            txtFldNames[i].Size = new System.Drawing.Size(w, h);
            this.Controls.Add(txtFldNames[i]);
            txtFldNames[i].ReadOnly = true;
            txtFldNames[i].BackColor = Color.White;
        }
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //what to do here?

        // Now you can access the global array variable.
        for (int i = 0; i < 15; i++)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(txtFldNames[i].Text);
        }
    }
}
```

And if you want to clean up the code a bit:

```
public partial class classMain : Form
{
    // Move your list to a global scope in the classMain form.
    TextBox[] txtFldNames = new TextBox[15];

    public frmMain()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void frmMain_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        int x = 155, y = 65, w = 300, h = 20;

        for (int i = 0; i < 15; i++)
        {
            y = y + 30;

            var t = new TextBox
            {
                Location = new System.Drawing.Point(x, y),
                Size = new System.Drawing.Size(w, h),
                ReadOnly = true,
                BackColor = Color.White
            };

            txtFldNames[i] = t;
            this.Controls.Add(t);
        }
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //what to do here?

        // Now you can access the global array variable.
        for (int i = 0; i < txtFldNames.Length; i++)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(txtFldNames[i].Text);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: @icebuken Always nice to hear =) Don't forget to accept the answer if it helped you.

Comment: thanks for the clean up tips. didn't knew that it could also be done this way.

Answer (score 1):

You need to be accessing the textboxes you created earlier, not new ones:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    for (int j = 0; j < 15; j++)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("" + txtFldNames[j].Text);
    }
}
```

If `txtFldNames` was a local variable in your load event then you need to change it to be an instance field of your form instead.

Comment: I already tried that one but it generates an error saying "the name 'txtFldNames' does not exist in the current context

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Enumerable.OfType` to find your TextBoxes:

```
foreach(TextBox txt in this.Controls.OfType<TextBox>())
{
    string text = txt.Text; 
}
```

(remember to add `using System.Linq;`)

You could also access your array via `foreach(TextBox txt in txtFldNames)`.

Your approach doesn't work since you are creating `new` TextBoxes in the loop instead of referencing the already existing.

Answer (score 0):

I am presuming from your code sample that `txtFldNames` is an instance variable (i.e. declared in the scope of the form, not within the form load event).

Therefore in your button click handler, you need to use the TextBox objects from the `txtFldNames` array - i.e. the objects you created when the form loaded. Your current code creates a new array of TextBox objects instead.

e.g.

```
foreach(TextBox textBox in tbFldNames) {
    MessageBox.Show(textBox.Text);
}
```

EDIT:

Following posting of full code, you need to make `txtFldNames` an instance variable.

i.e.

```
public partial class classMain : Form
{
    TextBox[] txtFldNames = new TextBox[15]; // <--- Move txtFldNames outside of your frmMain_Load() method.
```

Comment: already tried this too and has same error as what I replied to Servy